# How can I call a create method of a controller in another controller in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, controller

**I have two controllers one is Payments and one is Transactions, I need to call the create method of transactions inside the create method of payments. So that each time I create a payment a transaction is automatically created. How should I approach this?**

> ```
> module Api
> class PaymentsController < ApplicationController
>   before_action :set_payment, only: %i[ show update destroy ]
>
>   def index
>     @payments = Payment.all
>     render json: @payments
>   end
>   def show
>     render json: @payment
>   end
>   def create
>     @payment = Payment.new(payment_params)
>     if @payment.save
>       render json: 'Payment Is Made sucessfully'.to_json, status: :ok
>     else
>       render json: @payment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
>     end
>   end
>   private
>     def payment_params
>       params.permit(:currency, :amount, :payment_type, :payment_address)
>     end
> end
> end
> ```

> ```
> module Api
> class TransactionsController < ApplicationController
>   before_action :set_transaction, only: %i[show update destroy]
>
>   def index
>     @transactions = Transaction.all
>     render json: @transactions
>   end
>   def show
>     render json: @transaction
>   end
>   # POST /transactions
>   def create
>     @transaction = Transaction.new(transaction_params)
>     if @transaction.save
>       render json: @transaction, status: :created, location: @transaction
>     else
>       render json: @transaction.errors,status::unprocessable_entity
>     end
>   end
>   private
>   def transaction_params
>     params.permit(:transaction_type, :bank_name, :debit, :credit, :total_amount)
>   end
> end
> end
> ```

Comment: I suggest having a look at [NestedAttributes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First to note, MVC is just a convention or good way to organize your code.

You can simply do:

```
def create
  @transaction = Transaction.new(transaction_params)

  # You'll have to figure out how to get the params in here - maybe they are all derived from the transaction?
  @payment = Payment.new()

  @payment.save

  # handle payment error here too like below

  if @transaction.save
    render json: @transaction, status: :created, location: @transaction
  else
    render json: @transaction.errors,status::unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

However, this doesn't present itself well towards reusable code.

We have 2 options - put it into the model or introduce a service.

In the transaction model, we can create a function like:

```
class Transaction
  ...

  def self.create_with_payment(params)
    Transaction.create(params)
    Payment.create(params)

    # do whatever here to create and associate these
  end
```

or we can introduce a service object:

```
class TransactionPaymentCreator
  def call(params)
    Transaction.create(params)
    Payment.create(params)
  end
end
```

You can then call this in your controller:

```
def create
  service = TransactionPaymentCreator.new
  service.call
end
```

I'm leaving out a lot of detail like how to set these things up - but I hope to convey to you the general details - you have 3 options on how to make this work.

Here is a good article and resource on reading more for service objects if you decide to go that route:

https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/refactor-ruby-rails-service-object/

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to make a callback on your Payment model:

```rb
# payment.rb

after_create :create_transaction

def create_transaction
  Transaction.create(payment_id: id) # or whatever params you need in the transaction
end
```